# How to install and setup tftp server in Ubuntu 14.10 (utopic)?

Tags: server, 14.10, tftp

I was using 14.04 before, and I was able to setup and make tftp server and client work. Now that I upgrade to 14.10, tftp server isn't working anymore

Here's what I did:

1. Install the package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa
   ```
2. Edit config file as follows.

   `sudo vi /etc/default/tftpd-hpa`

   ```
   # /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
   TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
   TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"
   TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
   TFTP_OPTIONS="-s -c -l"
   ```
3. Create TFTP folder.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /tftpboot
   sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
   sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
   ```
4. Restart the app to apply new configuration.

   ```
   sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
   ```

([Source](http://vinobkaranath.blogspot.com/2014/06/install-tftp-server-in-ubuntu-1404.html))

At that time, I didn't know that `tftpd-hpa` is the package for TFTP server and `tftp-hpa` is for TFTP client so what I did was install another package for the TFTP CLIENT.

1. Install the following packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp
   ```
2. Change permission of `/etc/xinetd.d` directory.

   ```
   sudo chmod –R 777 xinetd.d
   ```
3. Create a file named tftp in `/etc/xinetd.d` and write the following:

   ```
   service tftp {
   socket_type = dgram
   protocol = UDP.
   WAIT = YES
   user = root
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args =-s /tftpboot
   disable = no
   per_source = 11
   cps = 100 2
   flags = IPv4
   }
   ```
4. Save and exit.
5. Create `tftpboot` directory and change permission.

   ```
   cd /
   sudo mkdir /tftpboot
   chmod –R 777 /tftpboot
   ```
6. Restart the service

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
   ```

This step by step process of installing TFTP server and another package for TFTP Client workis in 14.04 but not in 14.10, and I think that the 2nd installation and set up (`sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp`) is the culprit why TFTP server isn't working. I've already uninstalled the packages which I think isn't needed. But TFTP server still isn't working. What can I do to make TFTP server work?

Comment: I see no reason why it won't work on 14.10.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Hi after reading your comment I realized that I may have done something that ruined the configuration/set up of TFTP server. I've added details in my post. Kindly read it if you have time. Thank you. :)

Comment: Do what user3714598 described in second part of his post but DO NOT change permission of /etc/xinetd.d .
It loosens the security of system and it is not needed.

Comment: It's always a good idea to check the system logs. go to /var/log and look for tftpd and also take a look at syslog for clues.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please explain the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone looking for clarity my answer may help:

`tftpd-hpa` is a self-contained tftp server - it doesn't need xinetd configured to work, in fact some of the recommendations I've read will result in contention for port 69 between `tftpd-hpa` and `xinetd`!

The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/873476/976279)  elsewhere on this page from user [storm](https://askubuntu.com/users/434573/storm) is an example. I'm sure this `xinetd` configuration works with some other tftp package, but I don't see how it could with `tftpd-hpa`.

Take a look at the default configuration for `tftpd-hpa` in `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`:

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/srv/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS=":69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

Unless you need a solution with more options, you should make sure you ***do not*** configure `xinetd` to handle tftp or listen on port 69 (or just don't install it at all). Edit `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` as per your needs and then run `sudo systemctl restart tftpd-hpa` and you should be good. You can verify with this:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 69
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:69              0.0.0.0:*                           45262/in.tftpd
udp6       0      0 :::69                   :::*                                45262/in.tftpd
```