# How can I make my tftp server visible/available on my local network?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, tftp

I have looked at the following questions without success:

- [How to install and configure a tftp server on 14 04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581772/how-to-install-and-configure-a-tftp-server-on-14-04)
- [How to setup a tftp server in ubuntu 14 04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592010/how-to-setup-a-tftp-server-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- [How to install and setup tftp server in ubuntu 14 10 utopic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629296/how-to-install-and-setup-tftp-server-in-ubuntu-14-10-utopic)
- [How do i install and run a tftp server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201505/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-tftp-server)

I've tried using tftp-hpa, atftpd and tftp. I've returned to tftp as using the others made no difference.

So far I have:

Installed tftp

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp
```

Set up /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

Created the /tftpboot folder and ran the following for it:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
```

I have allowed port 69 through iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:tftp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:tftp
```

and restarted the service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

I can connect fine using localhost (same result if I explicitly use 127.0.0.1):

```
tftp localhost
tftp> status
Connected to localhost.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
tftp> get test
Received 21 bytes in 0.0 seconds
tftp> quit
```

However, none of my colleagues can access it from their machines (same network, same subnet mask) and, most importantly, I can't access it from the embedded board that I need it for (ethernet cables plugged into same switch).
I've been googling for hours and haven't found a fix yet.

The fact that it works locally would suggest its a firewall/port problem but port 69 is allowed on iptables and I'm not sure what else I an do.

Comment: Can you try telnet from your colleague for port 69 to your machine? If it does/doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: So how do you connect to this server from the other machine? Do you use that 127-address, or the actual public local address? Do you set the 69 port? Most clients expect port 21. You should give us those details!

Comment: I'm using `tftp 10.42.143.17` from another pc, and `load -b tftp://10.42.243.17/zbimage-linux-xload` from the embedded system. According to other questions and tutorials udp port 69 is the default for tftp.

Comment: @Gen Telnet on port 69 fails.

Comment: @AlexMeuer this means problem is at firewall inside your server or router. To be sure make same iptables rules for output, just change `INPUT` to `OUTPUT` and let me know if problem still exist.

Comment: @Gen Adding the OUTPUT rules fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: With problems like these, disable the firewall, then test again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have only `INPUT` rules, which means you only accept incoming traffic from port 69 but you have traffic going out aswell, that means you need to `ACCEPT` outgoing traffic aswell.

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
```